# Create a queue linked list in linear time

Tags: c, time-complexity, singly-linked-list

I came up with this way of creating a linked list in C:

```
void queue(Node ** head, Node * object)
{
    Node * tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    *tmp = *object;
    Node *last = get_Last((*head));
    if (last) {
        last->next = tmp;
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        (*head) = tmp;
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

The idea is rather simple, pass a pointer to an object to `queue(...)` then traverse the list to find the last node and then edit a few pointers. However what I don't exactly like is the `get_Last(...)` function:

```
Node * get_Last(Node * head)
{

    if (!head) {
        return NULL;
    }
    while (head->next) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

This function means that should `queue(...)` ever find itself in a loop then the algorithm I came up with has O(n²) time complexity which is just too much for something as simple as creating a linked list. What can be done to bring down the complexity to O(n)? I guess `queue(...)` still needs the address of the last node, but how do I obtain it without a loop?

Comment: Save the tail pointer. Or insert the new elements at the list's head.

Comment: And in order to conveniently store both the head and the tail of the list, create a separate structure to represent an overall list, independent of the `Node` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that items need to be inserted at the end of the list? Inserting/removing at the front of a linked list is `O(1)` for free.

If you do in fact want an efficient FIFO list, the best way to do this by far is to keep the address of the tail element. It requires only constant memory and allows `O(1)` inserts to the tail.

The most clear way to accomplish this would likely be to make a Queue struct that keeps a pointer to the head and tail, with utility functions accepting a pointer to Queue for enqueue and dequeue operations.